# Backgroundworker using Action Type in c#

Tags: c#

I am trying to simplifying using a backgroundworker in c# using Action type, but i am not 
able to assign b and c method that passed as parameter to dowork and runworkercompleted
for the backgroundworker _bw ?

```
Action<DoWorkEventArgs, Action, Action> th = (a, b, c) =>
{
    BackgroundWorker _bw = new BackgroundWorker();
    _bw.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(b);
    _bw.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(c);
    _bw.RunWorkerAsync(a);
};
```

both methods would have this signature
void methodname()

Changing type from Action helped, but now complete method is not working

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Action
        <DoWorkEventArgs, DoWorkEventHandler, RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler>
        th = (a, b, c) =>
        {
            BackgroundWorker _bw = new BackgroundWorker();
            _bw.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(b);
            _bw.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(c);
            _bw.RunWorkerAsync(a);
        };

        th.Invoke(null,
        new DoWorkEventHandler(DoWork),
        new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(complete));
    }

    public static void DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Doing work . . .");
    }

    public static void complete(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Doing work Completed.");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot assign an Action as the event handler for [DoWork](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.dowork%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [RunWorkerCompleted](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.runworkercompleted%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) directly because the signatures that the events expect differs significantly from the signature that an Action delegate has. You have two options:

### Leave the signatures of b and c, but change how the event handlers are registered

```
Action<DoWorkEventArgs, Action, Action> th = (a, b, c) =>
{
    BackgroundWorker _bw = new BackgroundWorker();
    _bw.DoWork += (sender, args) => b();
    _bw.RunWorkerCompleted += (sender, args) => c();
    _bw.RunWorkerAsync(a);
};
```

### Change the signatures of b and c to match the event signatures

```
Action<DoWorkEventArgs, DoWorkEventHandler, RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler> th = (a, b, c) =>
{
    BackgroundWorker _bw = new BackgroundWorker();
    _bw.DoWork = new DoWorkEventHandler(b);
    _bw.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(c);
    _bw.RunWorkerAsync(a);
};
```

I'd suggest the latter because especially in RunWorkerCompleted you might want to analyze whether the job completed successfully. If the handler for this event does not receive any parameters, you cannot do this.
In any case, make sure that you dispose the BackgroundWorker object correctly after it has completed.

Comment: Your answer works, but the complete method i atttached to RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler does not fire.

Comment: It now works perfectly, i just needed to rebuild it.